# how to make Andengine button

Tags: java, andengine

Can someone direct me to an example which shows me how to make a button which follows the camera in my game scene?

I am using Andengine.

Comment: You question is too incomplete and unclear.

Comment: is it ok now can u understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make the "button" from a sprite. To make the camera follow you simply need to set the button as the chase entity

```
camera.setChaseEntity(button);
```